# Firestore cannot typecast array in c#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve a document from firestore in my c# application but for some reason when I typecast the array coming from firestore it is returning null. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

C# Code

```
    CollectionReference citiesRef = db.Collection("Astrologer");
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await citiesRef.Document(docid).GetSnapshotAsync();
    Dictionary<string,object> dic = documentSnapshot.ToDictionary();
    if (dic.ContainsKey("offers") && dic["offers"] != null)
    {
        var testarray = dic["offers"]; //Array data correctly showing here
        var type = testarray.GetType();
        var offersinarray = testarray as string[];  //this is returning null
        if (offersinarray!=null&&offersinarray.Count > 0)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the `type` of `testarray`. Is the conversion from `type` to `string[]` possible?

`as` returns `null` when the conversion is not possible - see description of [as operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator).

> The **as** operator explicitly converts the result of an expression to a given reference or nullable value type. If the conversion is not possible, the **as** operator returns **null**.

Comment: When i use GetType() on testarray i am getting `System.Collections.Generic.List1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]`, which should be able to be converted to string array shouldn't it??

Comment: No. Your `dict` elements are of type `object` (`Dictionary<string,**object**> dic`). The underlying type of dictionary elements is `List<object>`, so conversion `var x= testarray as List<object>` should be possible. Assuming x will be not null, you could try `x.Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and  actually  this thread helped me solve it.
There is `Android.Runtime.JavaList` that I use but if you are not on the android platform there must be something similar.  The `Android.Runtime.JavaList`  I found when I checked the type of the object as you do `var type = testarray.GetType();` ...this returned `Android.Runtime.JavaList`

What works fine for me:

```
Android.Runtime.JavaList list = (Android.Runtime.JavaList)doc.Get(propertyName);

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            myList.Add((string)item); //I need strings but you can parse it anyhow
        }
```